# Lexicographic Rank of a Set Partitioned Into Groups

Tags: c++, combinatorics

Given a set of 8 sequential numbers `{0..7}` partitioned into 4 groups of size 2, with the numbers in each group in ascending order, how can a rank be generated for the set?  The rank should be in lexicographic order, and preferably the algorithm should be linear in complexity.

Examples of the partitioning:

```
{{0 1} {2 3} {4 5} {6 7}} // Rank 0
...
{{6 7} {4 5} {2 3} {0 1}} // Rank 2519
```

Because the numbers in each group are in ascending order, the groups are effectively treated like combinations, not permutations, so a group containing e.g. `{5 4}` will never occur.

How can this set of numbers be ranked sequentially in the range `[0, 2520)` (`8C2 * 6C2 * 4C2`)?

At present I compute the rank of each group as an 8C2 combination, then combine each rank together by treating it as a base-28 number.  This obviously leaves gaps in the ranking, which is undesirable in my case.  But, for what it's worth, here is how I'm currently ranking.

```
#include <array>
using std::array;
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// Calculates n!.
uint32_t factorial(uint32_t n)
{
  return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
}

// Calculate nCk: n!/((n-k)!*k!).
uint32_t choose(uint32_t n, uint32_t k)
{
  return (n < k)
    ? 0
    : factorial(n) / (factorial(n - k) * factorial(k));
}

template<size_t N, size_t K>
class CombinationRanker
{
  array<array<uint32_t, K+1>, N+1> choices;

public:
  /**
   * Initialize a precomputed array of nCk (N and K inclusive).
   */
  CombinationRanker()
  {
    for (unsigned n = 0; n <= N; ++n)
      for (unsigned k = 0; k <= K; ++k)
        this->choices[n][k] = choose(n, k);
  }

  /**
   * Get the rank of a combination.
   * @param comb A combination array of size K in ascending order.
   */
  uint32_t rank(const array<uint8_t, K> comb) const
  {
    // Formula: (nCk) - ((n-c_1)Ck) - ((n-c_2)C(k-1)) - ... - ((n-c_k)C1)
    // That assumes 1-based combinations with ranks starting at 1, so each
    // element in the combination has 1 added to it, and the end result has 1
    // subtracted from it to make the rank 0-based.
    uint32_t rank = this->choices[N][K];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; ++i)
      rank -= this->choices[N - (comb[i] + 1)][K - i];

    return rank - 1;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  CombinationRanker<8, 2> ranker;

  array<array<uint8_t, 2>, 4> nums =
  {{
    {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}
  }};

  // Horribly sparse rank.
  unsigned rank =
    ranker.rank(nums[0]) * 28 * 28 * 28 +
    ranker.rank(nums[1]) * 28 * 28 +
    ranker.rank(nums[2]) * 28 +
    ranker.rank(nums[3]);

  cout << rank << endl; // 10835, but I want 0.

  return 0;
}
```

I've tagged the post as C++ as that's the language I'm using; however, answers in another language are fine.  It's more of a math question, but I'm looking for an answer that I can understand as a programmer, not a mathematician, and a code snippet would be helpful in that regard.

Comment: Treat the rank as a variable-base number (first digit base 28, second digit base 15, third digit base 6, omitted fourth digit base 1). The rank of any pair will depend on what precedes it and is position dependent (the rank for `{2, 3}` in the second position will be 0 if the first position is `{0, 1}` and 5 (I think) if the first position is `{0, 4}` because the first 5 will contain a 1.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ah yes, I see what you're saying, and I'm able to calculate the rank now by hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.  It's quadratic in complexity, which is not the greatest, but it does the trick.  The basic algorithm is as follows.

Given a set of sequential numbers from [0..7] partitioned into unordered pairs, loop over each pair and find its rank among pairs that
exclude numbers preceding it.  Then multiplying each rank by its variable
base.  The variable bases for each rank are `6C2*4C2*2C2`, `4C2*2C2`, and `2C2`.

As an example, for `{{2,3}, {6,7}, {4,5}, {0,1}}`:

- `{2, 3}` has rank 13.
- `{6, 7}` has rank 14 among pairs excluding 2 and 3.
- `{4, 5}` has rank 5 among pairs excluding 2, 3, 6, and 7.
- `{0, 1}` is ignored.

Altogether, `13*6C2*4C2*2C2 + 14*4C2*2C2 + 5*2C2 = 1259`

Other examples:

- `{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}} -> 0`
- `{{2, 3}, {6, 7}, {4, 5}, {0, 1}} -> 1259`
- `{{2, 4}, {0, 1}, {3, 5}, {6, 7}} -> 1260`
- `{{6, 7}, {4, 5}, {2, 3}, {0, 1}} -> 2519`

Here's algorithm in code.  I've hard coded quite a bit for brevity.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <array>
using std::array;
#include <cstdint>

typedef array<uint8_t, 2> pair_t;

/**
 * @param set A set of 8 sequential numbers, [0..7], partitioned into unordered
 * pairs.
 */
uint32_t rank(const array<pair_t, 4>& set) {
  // All 28 (8C2) possible unordered subsets of the set of 8 sequential
  // numbers, [0..7], in lexicographic order.  Hard-coded here for brevity.
  array<pair_t, 28> pairs = {{
    {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}, {0, 6}, {0, 7},
            {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7},
                    {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7},
                            {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 7},
                                    {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7},
                                            {5, 6}, {5, 7},
                                                    {6, 7},
  }};

  // Variable base for each rank "digit" (the base corresponding to the rank of
  // each subset): 6C2*4C2*2C2, 4C2*2C2, 2C2.  Again, hard-coded for brevity.
  array<uint32_t, 3> bases = {{90, 6, 1}};

  // Now rank the set.
  uint32_t rank = 0;
  // Rank among this many pairs.  For N=8, 8C2->6C2->4C2->2C2 (28->15->6->1).
  unsigned numRemaining = 28; // N*(N-1)/2
  array<pair_t, 28> remaining = pairs;

  // Loop over the first three unordered subsets.  The last isn't needed for
  // ranking--n from [0...(N-2)/2).
  for (unsigned n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
  {
    unsigned remainingInd = 0;
    const pair_t& sPair = set[n];

    for (unsigned r = 0; r < numRemaining; ++r)
    {
      const pair_t& rPair = remaining[r];

      if (sPair == rPair)
      {
        // Found the pair: rank it relative to the ramining pairs, and multiply
        // it by the base for digit n.
        rank += r * bases[n];
      }
      else if (
        sPair[0] != rPair[0] && sPair[0] != rPair[1] &&
        sPair[1] != rPair[0] && sPair[1] != rPair[1]
      )
      {
        // The pair excludes the numbers in set[n], so keep it in the
        // list of remaining pairs for the next digit's rank.
        remaining[remainingInd++] = rPair;
      }
    }

    // Number of remaining pairs.
    numRemaining = remainingInd;
  }

  return rank;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Examples pairs.
  array<array<pair_t, 4>, 7> sets = {{
    {{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}}},
    {{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}}},
    {{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 7}, {5, 6}}},
    {{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}, {4, 7}}},
    // snip
    {{{2, 3}, {6, 7}, {4, 5}, {0, 1}}},
    // snip
    {{{6, 7}, {4, 5}, {1, 3}, {0, 2}}},
    {{{6, 7}, {4, 5}, {2, 3}, {0, 1}}},
  }};

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
  {
    const array<pair_t, 4>& set = sets[i];

    cout << rank(set) << ": ";

    for (unsigned j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
      cout << '{' << (unsigned)set[j][0] << ", " << (unsigned)set[j][1] << '}';

    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: {0, 1}{2, 3}{4, 5}{6, 7}
1: {0, 1}{2, 3}{4, 6}{5, 7}
2: {0, 1}{2, 3}{4, 7}{5, 6}
3: {0, 1}{2, 3}{5, 6}{4, 7}
1259: {2, 3}{6, 7}{4, 5}{0, 1}
2518: {6, 7}{4, 5}{1, 3}{0, 2}
2519: {6, 7}{4, 5}{2, 3}{0, 1}
```